# Python discord-bot

Tags: python-3.9

```
#-----Import Libraries-----#
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
client= commands.Bot(command_prefix='#', intents=intents)


#Tictactoe
player1=""
player2=""
turn=""
gameover =True
board=[]

winningConditions = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
]


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    guild_count = 0

    for guild in client.guilds:
        print(f' - id: {guild.id}   name: {guild.name}')
        guild_count+=1

    print('Test run is in ' + str(guild_count) + ' servers.')
    

client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if '#tictactoe' in message.content:
        global player1
        global player2 
        global turn
        global gameover
        global count
        global board
        await message.channel.send('Who do you want to play against?')
        try:
            message=await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.author==message.author and m.channel==message.channel, timeout=15)


        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            message.channel.send('you ran out of time')
            
        else:
            if gameover:
                global board
                board=[":white_large_square:",":white_large_square:",":white_large_square:",
                    ":white_large_square:",":white_large_square:",":white_large_square:",
                    ":white_large_square:",":white_large_square:",":white_large_square:"]
                turn=""
                gameover=False
                count=0

                player1=message.author
                player2=message.mentions[0]

                #print board
                line=""
                for x in range(len(board)):
                    if x==2 or x==5 or x==8:
                        line+=""+board[x]
                        await message.channel.send(line)
                        line=""
                    else:
                        line+=""+board[x]

                #who goes first
                num=random.randint(1,2)
                if num==1:
                    turn=player1
                    message.channel.send("it is <@"+str(player1.id)+">'s turn") 
                else:
                    turn=player2
                    await message.channel.send("it is <@"+str(player2.id)+">'s turn")           
            else:
                await message.channel.send("A game is already in progress")
            



#-----Execute bot-----#
client.run('OTMwMDYzMzMzOTY3NjgzNjM0.Ydwa-g.ds5OBaMSOEAUL72AYkSURgrdl54')
```

And this is the error I keep getting. When i tried the same code in another laptop it worked although i have the same libraries.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nagariamf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 300, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\Nagariamf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 254, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\FIDYAN\python\projecttk.py", line 96, in <module>
    client.run('OTMwMDYzMzMzOTY3NjgzNjM0.Ydwa-g.ds5OBaMSOEAUL72AYkSURgrdl54')
  File "C:\Users\Nagariamf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Nagariamf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nagariamf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Nagariamf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Nagariamf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 304, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000024447E19670>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nagariamf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\Nagariamf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\Nagariamf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\Nagariamf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: Here is what I can see: You've seem to missed a "@" so your `Client.event` decorator is not doing it's job! Also Shared your discord API key with everyone on the internet! The error log you've reluctantly provided (`discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized`), combined with the fact that you said the code works on another machine, signals to me that this is probably an issue that can be solved by maybe getting a new API Token? Or checking if discord has your new IP address blocked for some reason? I think you should test with a small code just to make sure you have access to the bot.

Comment: i fixed that , still has the same error